# Allow UnsafeUpdates property

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have tried to write a code in object model using C#.Net for accessing a sharepoint list items and document library, I have to set allowunsafeupdates property to be true.

Is it massive security problem to the whole site..

Could anyone clarify this ...

Comment: Check out these articles: [https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates/](https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates/) [https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates-part-2/](https://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates-part-2/) They are a very thorough look at `AllowUnsafeUpdates` and might answers some question you have.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest risk on setting [SPSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allowunsafeupdates.aspx) to true is in GET operations because it open your site to cross site scripting.

Have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213882/best-pattern-for-allowunsafeupdates) for further details on using the true value within a safe pattern usage.